# SAML 2.0 Identity Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, saml, saml-2.0, idp

Is it worth to consider SAML 2.0 as Identity Provider for **legacy WIF clients**?
Are there some benefits comparing to Identity Server 4 or other OpenId/OAuth2 based solutions?

Answer (score 0):

WIF only provides the WS-Fed protocol.

It will not run as a SAML client.

idsrv4 uses OpenID Connect out the box. It has plugins for both WS-Fed and SAML.